# Display table rows depending on child nodes coming from backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little challenge with a table

Here is the `table`

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th ng-repeat="value in drilldownReport.columns">
         {{ drilldownReport.columnNames[value] }}
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="offer in drilldownReport.data">
          <td>{{ offer.criteria.id }}</td>
          <td ng-repeat="value in drilldownReport.columns">
            {{ drilldownReport.fixDisplay(offer.overall[value]) }}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="offer in drilldownReport.childsNodes">
          <td>{{ offer.criteria.id }}</td>
          <td ng-repeat="value in drilldownReport.columns">
            {{ offer.overall[value] }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

that data comes from the controller like this

```
    .then(function (data) {
      vm.data = data;
      vm.data.map(function(items) {
        console.log(items.childs);
        vm.childsNodes = items.childs;
      });
    }
```

where `vm.data` returns this array of objs

```
[  
   {  
      "type":"offer",
      "criteria":{  
         "type":"offer_id",
         "id":"55e8f8d43744b0cd38bfb6bd"
      },
      "overall":{  
         "cost_per_click":0,
         "offer_price":0
      },
      "childs":[  
         {  
            "type":"offer",
            "criteria":{  
               "type":"browser",
               "id":"Firefox"
            },
            "overall":{  
               "cost_per_click":0,
               "offer_price":0
            },
            "childs":[  
               {  
                  "type":"offer",
                  "criteria":{  
                     "type":"browser",
                     "id":"Firefox"
                  },
                  "overall":{  
                     "cost_per_click":0,
                     "offer_price":0
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "type":"offer",
                  "criteria":{  
                     "type":"browser",
                     "id":"Chrome"
                  },
                  "overall":{  
                     "cost_per_click":0,
                     "offer_price":0
                  },
                  "childs":[  
                     {  
                        "type":"offer",
                        "criteria":{  
                           "type":"browser",
                           "id":"Firefox"
                        },
                        "overall":{  
                           "cost_per_click":0,
                           "offer_price":0
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "type":"offer",
                        "criteria":{  
                           "type":"browser",
                           "id":"Chrome"
                        },
                        "overall":{  
                           "cost_per_click":0,
                           "offer_price":0
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "type":"offer",
            "criteria":{  
               "type":"browser",
               "id":"Chrome"
            },
            "overall":{  
               "cost_per_click":0,
               "offer_price":0
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

there you can see `childs` with the exact same properties that his parent node has (type, criteria and overall). `childs` is an array of objs, within every object of the array `childs` sometimes you will see `childs` as the same exact object, and within `childs` could be another `childs` and so on, did you get it ? like a big chain of `childs`, and I will need to render that in the table. The amount of `childs` is countless, sometimes could be only 1, or sometimes 40.

What do you recommend ?

**EDIT**

just in case you want to know about the columns and columnNames

```
vm.columns = [
  "offer_price",
  "cost_per_click"
]

vm.columnNames = {
  "offer_price": "Offer Price",
  "cost_per_click": "CPC"
};
```

I saw [this](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/) which is similar to what I need, but I don't know how to adapt that to my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive and call it recursively

Element.html

```
<tr>
    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
    <td>{{data.value}}</td>
</tr>
<element ng-repeat="child in data.children" data="child"></element>
```

elementDirective.js

```
.directive('element', function() {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'path/Element.html',
    scope: {
        data: '='
    }
});
```

On your main html:

```
<table>
    <tr><th> ... </th></tr>
    <element data="drilldownReport.data">
</table>
```